GPU requirements for training vs inference
How to estimate GPU requirements for model Inference vs model training/fine tuning.
If it's differ, then in what ratio? just as a rule of thumb

A user claimed about llama "For FULL model training baseline is training = 4x inference. 1x for weights (same for inference) 1x for gradients 2x for optimiser (if it’s Adam)". For transformer models I've worked with, I used 16-32x smaller per_device_train_batch_size for fine-tuning, but it probably depends on implementation a lot.
